# woocommerce rating stars bugs : "SSSSS"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce with my Website, but it keep making bugged star ratings like "SSSSS" and shape of stars overlapped.

It has been figured out number of "S" is the ratings, however, it should have been replaced with the colored star.

How should I fix the code?

[image]

will try to attach entire library of woocommerce source code. So please tell me if it is needed.

Below is the code of what I am suspicious of now.
review.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Display single product reviews (comments)
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.2
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

if ( ! comments_open() ) {
    return;
}

?>fs
<div id="reviews" class="woocommerce-Reviews">
    <div id="comments">
        <h2 class="woocommerce-Reviews-title"><?php
            if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' && ( $count = $product->get_review_count() ) )
                printf( _n( '%s review for %s%s%s', '%s reviews for %s%s%s', $count, 'woocommerce' ), $count, '<span>', get_the_title(), '</span>' );
            else
                _e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
        ?></h2>

        <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

            <ol class="commentlist">
                <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
            </ol>

            <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
                echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
                paginate_comments_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args', array(
                    'prev_text' => '&larr;',
                    'next_text' => '&rarr;',
                    'type'      => 'list',
                ) ) );
                echo '</nav>';
            endif; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php _e( 'There are no reviews yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_review_rating_verification_required' ) === 'no' || wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->id ) ) : ?>

        <div id="review_form_wrapper">
            <div id="review_form">
                <?php
                    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

                    $comment_form = array(
                        'title_reply'          => have_comments() ? __( 'Add a review', 'woocommerce' ) : sprintf( __( 'Be the first to review &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'woocommerce' ), get_the_title() ),
                        'title_reply_to'       => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'comment_notes_after'  => '',
                        'fields'               => array(
                            'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
                                        '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" aria-required="true" required /></p>',
                            'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
                                        '<input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" aria-required="true" required /></p>',
                        ),
                        'label_submit'  => __( 'Submit', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'logged_in_as'  => '',
                        'comment_field' => ''
                    );

                    if ( $account_page_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) {
                        $comment_form['must_log_in'] = '<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a review.', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( $account_page_url ) ) . '</p>';
                    }

                    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' ) {
                        $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<p class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">' . __( 'Your Rating', 'woocommerce' ) .'</label><select name="rating" id="rating" aria-required="true" required>
                            <option value="">' . __( 'Rate&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="5">' . __( 'Perfect', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="4">' . __( 'Good', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="3">' . __( 'Average', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="2">' . __( 'Not that bad', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="1">' . __( 'Very Poor', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        </select></p>';
                    }

                    $comment_form['comment_field'] .= '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . __( 'Your Review', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <span class="required">*</span></label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true" required></textarea></p>';

                    comment_form( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', $comment_form ) );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-verification-required"><?php _e( 'Only logged in customers who have purchased this product may leave a review.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Another suspicion : rating.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Rating
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/rating.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.2
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'no' ) {
    return;
}

$rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
$review_count = $product->get_review_count();
$average      = $product->get_average_rating();

if ( $rating_count > 0 ) : ?>

    <div class="woocommerce-product-rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <div class="star-rating" title="<?php printf( __( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average ); ?>">
            <span style="width:<?php echo ( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ); ?>%">
                <strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating"><?php echo esc_html( $average ); ?></strong> <?php printf( __( 'out of %s5%s', 'woocommerce' ), '<span itemprop="bestRating">', '</span>' ); ?>
                <?php printf( _n( 'based on %s customer rating', 'based on %s customer ratings', $rating_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span itemprop="ratingCount" class="rating">' . $rating_count . '</span>' ); ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?><a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span itemprop="reviewCount" class="count">' . $review_count . '</span>' ); ?>)</a><?php endif ?>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding a short css to your style.css
this worked for me:

```
.woocommerce .star-rating span{
font-family:star;
}
```